# recebendo array plsql em javascript

Tags: javascript, pl-sql

Criei um cursor em pl, agora estou tentando passar os registros para um *array* do javascript para criar gráficos, o `newData`  irá receber os dados do cursor.

Javascript criado é esse:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

     var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

     var newData = [['Ano', 'Vendas'],
        ['2004',  1000       ],
        ['2005',  1170],
        ['2006',  660],
        ['2007',  1030],
        ['2008',  1530]];


     // determine the number of rows and columns.
      var numRows = newData.length;
      var numCols = newData[0].length;

      // in this case the first column is of type 'string'.
      dataTable.addColumn('string', newData[0][0]);

      // all other columns are of type 'number'.
      for (var i = 1; i < numCols; i++)
        dataTable.addColumn('number', newData[0][i]);           

      // now add the rows.
      for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++)
        dataTable.addRow(newData[i]);    

    var options = {
      title: 'Vendas anual'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, amigo, e qual é o problema do código?

Comment: Está usando alguma linguagem server-side ? PHP, ASP ou outra ? Faça a requisição por ajax de uma página que carrega sua SP em SQL, retorna um array em `json` e pega no javascript.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver da seguinte forma, bem simples
******************
     var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var newData = Array();');
        FOR rec_dados IN cur_dados LOOP
          htp.p('newData.push(["' || rec_dados.retorno || '", ' || rec_dados.registro || ']);');
        END LOOP;

Comment: @MauricioMendes podes juntar uma resposta aqui? em vez do comentário com a solução...